Cannot render recursive component using Vue3 CDN
I want to build project with Vue3 CDN (because project environment cannot run npm) so I try to create component with html+CDN.
But when I try to create recursive component, It just render top-level element.
Is there any solution to solve this problem?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <title>Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <menu-comp v-for="item in message" :key="item.id" :item="item"></menu-comp>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

<script type="module">
    const {createApp, ref, } = Vue
    const MenuComp = {
        template: `
            <li>{{ item.menuName }}
                <ul v-if="item.subMenu.length>0">
                    <component is="menu-comp" v-for="subs in item.subMenu" :key="subs.id" :item="subs"></component>
                </ul>
            </li>
        `,
        props: ['item'],
    }
    const app = createApp({
        setup() {
            const message = ref([])
            return {
                message
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getMenus();
        },
        components: {
            "menu-comp": MenuComp,
        },

        methods: {
            getMenus() {
                axios.get('/api/menu', {
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                }).then(r => {
                    const {data} = r;
                    this.message = data.results;
                    console.log(r);
                });
            }
        }
    }).mount('#app')

</script>

But When I render this page
<div id="app" data-v-app="">
<ul>
<li>test1 <ul>
<menu-comp item="[object Object]"></menu-comp>
</ul>
</li>
<li>test2
 <!--v-if-->
</li>
</ul>
</div>
``


Then for an infinit recursion like you want, another way is to use API composition for explicit recursion
//...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <title>Form Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <menu-comp
          v-for="item in message"
          :key="item.id"
          :item="item"
        ></menu-comp>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
      const { createApp, defineComponent, ref, h } = Vue;

      const MenuComp = defineComponent({
        name: "MenuComp",
        props: ["item"],
        setup(props) {
          return () =>
            h("li", [
              props.item.menuName,
              props.item.subMenu && props.item.subMenu.length
                ? h(
                    "ul",
                    props.item.subMenu.map((sub) =>
                      h(MenuComp, { item: sub, key: sub.id })
                    )
                  )
                : null,
            ]);
        },
      });

      const app = createApp({
        setup() {
          const message = ref([
            {
              menuName: "first",
              id: 1,
              subMenu: [
                {
                  menuName: "sub first",
                  id: 11,
                  subMenu: [],
                },
                {
                  menuName: "sub second",
                  id: 12,
                  subMenu: [],
                },
              ],
            },
          ]);
          return {
            message,
          };
        },
        components: {
          "menu-comp": MenuComp,
        },
      }).mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

//...


For the expected result, why not use slot inside your component, and inject the component itself afterwards?.
For example :
<div id="app">
      <ul>
        <menu-comp v-for="item in message" :key="item.id" :item="item">
          {{message.menuName}}
          <menu-comp
            v-for="subItem in item.subMenu"
            :key="subItem.id"
            :item="subItem"
            >{{subItem.menuName}}</menu-comp
          >
        </menu-comp>
      </ul>
    </div>


const MenuComp = {
      template: `
            <li>{{ item.menuName }}
                <ul v-if="item.subMenu?.length>0">
                    <slot/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        `,
      props: ["item"],
    };


This is a good solution when menu depth is 2. But my menu depth maximum is over 5 then I have to do another way.

ok, I will suggest to use API composition for explicit recursion
